# Dynamic Navigation Bar in Ember

Tags: ember.js

I have an Ember app where I am trying to have a navigation bar that allows me to change the navigation items for different routes.

Initially, I had the navigation using a lazy loaded `navItems` property on the application model.
But, now I have my first route where the `navItems` no longer represent what needs to populate the navigation bar items.
Right now, I am using a render helper similar to this:

```
{{render 'nav_menu' navItems}}
```

From there, I have a `nav_menu` template:

```
<a href="#">Jump To Category</a>
<div class="dropdown">
    <ul>
        {{#each}}
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="skip" {{bind-attr gumby-goto=gotoSlug}} gumby-offset="-120">{{name}}</a>
            </li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
</div>
```

And the view looks like this:

```
class App.NavMenuView extends Ember.View
    tagName: 'li'

    didInsertElement: ->
        Ember.run.later(this, @initializeGumby, 1000)

    initializeGumby: ->
        Gumby.init()
```

The run later is really a hack since the view finishes rendering before the context from the view is in the DOM (and to wait for the ids that it will jump to to exist).

So...
How would I go about making it so that the context of the `nav_menu` view could be changed, so that I can update the values in routes (and then have a hook to fire my DOM listeners too)?

I have created a jsbin to outline a bit of what I have going so far: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/cefutoge/1/

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution that feels really good once I was able to figure it out.

The trick was to start with the NavItemsController and make it extend Ember.ArrayController.
From there, add an observer that checks for changes of the content of the controller to reinitialize Gumby so that the scroll to works properly.

```
App.NavItemsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  contentHasChanged: function () {
    Gumby.init();
  }.observes('content')
});
```

Then, set up the application route to listen for a `changeNavItems` action:

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    actions: {
        changeNavItems: function (links) {
            this.controllerFor('navItems').set('content', links);
        }
    }
});
```

This allows the navItems to be set as they change from either a route (for dealing with initialized or transition data events), a controller (for dealing with application state events), or views/components (for changes based on user input).
This action will bubble up through controllers, and routes until it finally reaches the ApplicationRoute.

So, then it is just a matter of using the `send` function in a route, controller, or view.
In this case, the IndexRoute will do:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    afterModel: function (model, transition) {
        transition.send('changeNavItems', model.links);
    }
});
```

First, to discuss the use of `afterModel`:
While `setupController` would be a bit easier since `this.send` could be used instead, it does not fit the use case here.
`setupController` would make sense if the navBar lived deeper into the application or required the current route's controller to exist.
But, the nav bar has nothing to do with the IndexController state, once the model is loaded, then the links can be built.

The using `transition.send` from what I can tell allows the action to be triggered either on the same run loop as the transition or possibly the loop right after (would like to know on that one).
Once the action is triggered, no matching action is found on the IndexRoute so it bubbles up to the ApplicationRoute.
`changeNavItems` is called and then it goes and sets the `content` for the NavItemsController loaded in memory to the links variable.

A full working example can be found at http://jsbin.com/cefutoge/8/edit